# C libpcap API extracting DNS query

Tags: c, libpcap

I am trying to extract a DNS query from an captured DNS packet with libpcap api, however there must be a problem with my structures, after the last cast (using struct question) the `char* name`  pointer is pointing  at **correct adress**, the start of the query name, however it contains only

```
42 45 20 00
```

but it should

```
20 45 48 45 50 45 50 45 48 45 4d 45 46 43 4f 45 44 45 50 45 4e 43 41 43 41 43
41 43 41 43 41 41 41 00 00 20 00 01
```

The code is here

```
struct dnshdr{
    uint16_t id;
    uint16_t flags;
    uint16_t ques;
    uint16_t anRR;
    uint16_t auRR;
    uint16_t addRR;
};

struct question{
    char * name;
    uint16_t type;
    uint16_t cls;
};



void packetProc(u_char *args, const struct pcap_pkthdr *header,const u_char *packet){
   struct iphdr *IP_header;
   struct udphdr *UDP_header;
   struct dnshdr *DNS_header;
   struct question *ques;

   IP_header =  (struct iphdr*)    (packet + sizeof(struct ethhdr));
   UDP_header = (struct udphdr*)   (packet + sizeof(struct iphdr)  + sizeof(struct ethhdr));
   DNS_header = (struct dnshdr*)   (packet + sizeof(struct iphdr)  + sizeof(struct ethhdr)  +  sizeof(struct udphdr) );
   ques =       (struct question*) (packet + sizeof(struct ethhdr) + sizeof(struct iphdr)   +  sizeof(struct udphdr) + sizeof(struct dnshdr)-1 ); //fatal       
}
```

I am honestly puzzled what to do here

Comment: Can we reproduce the problem? What are the parameters to `packetProc` function, so I can get the same results as you do? I guess `u_char` is `unsigned char`? Are you sure you have no padding in your structs? Can you post sizeofs of `struct iphdr`, `struct ethhdr`, `struct udphdr`, .... ? Why do you have `struct question` with `char * name` pointer, are you sure in the packed there's a `char *` pointer to some location?

Comment: Another point: You cannot assume, that the IP header has a fixed size, there could be IP options enlarging the header. The correct way to determine the size is `IP_header->ihl * 4`, not `sizeof(struct iphdr)`. You have to check, of course, that you do not overrun any packet boundaries, since the field is filled by the remote peer.

Answer (score 1):

```
struct question{
    char * name;
    uint16_t type;
    uint16_t cls;
};
```

the way you use this struct is invalid. `char *` is a pointer to memory location containing characters. DNS query does not have a pointer value to your computer memory location containing characters, the query **contains** those characters. However the length of the DNS query name (ie. `char name[how much should be put here]`) is calculated from the length of the udp message. You can:

```
struct question_after_name_s { 
        uint16_t type;
        uint16_t cls;
};

...
const size_t namepos = 2*6; // name position in bytes form the beginning of the DNS query, this should be equal to 'sizeof(struct ethhdr) + sizeof(struct iphdr)   +  sizeof(struct udphdr) + sizeof(struct dnshdr)-1 ' from your code
char *name = (char*)&packet[namepos]; // the pointer name should point to the location in packet after namepos bytes
const size_t packetlen = header->len; // I guess this is received DNS query length obtained from libcap
const size_t querytypeandclasslen = 2*2; // length of the query type and query class, should be equal to sizeof(struct question_after_name_s)
const size_t namelen = packetlen - namepos - querytypeandclasslen;
printf("DNS query name = '%.*s'\n", namelen, name);
struct question_after_name_s *ptr = (void*)&packet[namepos + namelen];
//or
struct question_after_name_s *ptr = (void*)&packet[];
```

Of course such casting is correct only, if your compiler does not insert any padding between members of the structure (hope you use gcc compiler with `attribute((packed))` on those structs) and you call `ntohl` family functions or `be16toh` family functions to convert between the packet endianess and your host endianess.